# Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Long.<init>() in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am getting this error while reading a *student* object from database.

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.lang.Long]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Long.<init>()
org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:107)
```

#### Full stack trace:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.lang.Long]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Long.<init>()
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.lang.Long]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Long.<init>()
    org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveModelAttribute(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:775)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:368)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:172)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Long.<init>()
    java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveModelAttribute(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:775)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:368)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:172)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

#### File *Student.java*

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Student")
public class Student implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="studentId")
    Long studentId;

    @Column(name="studentName")
    String studentName;
```

#### File *Controller.java*

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/read.html")
    public String readStudent(Model model, @ModelAttribute("studentId") Long studentId) {
        Student student = null;
        studentId = 2l;
        try{
            student = serviceFile.readStudent(studentId);
        }catch(Exception e){
            model.addAttribute("message", "Some thing went wrong !!!! Exception occoured");
            return "message";
        }
        model.addAttribute("student", student);
        return "read";
    }
```

#### File *daoImpl.java*

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class DaoImplFile implements DaoFile {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Student read(Long studentId) throws NullPointerException {
        Student student = entityManager.find(Student.class, studentId);
        if (student!=null) {
            return student;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the entire stacktrace

Comment: @Bunti edited with full stack trace

Comment: Can you try changing `Long` to `long`?

Comment: @darshan mehta i have tried with both long  / Long, getting the same error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `@ModelAttribute("studentId") Long studentId` is the source of the problem, because Spring doesn't find a method that can provide this `Long` object, so it tries to instantiate one and pass it as a method argument. **To solve this problem** you can either:

- **Delete @ModelAttribue from the method argument**

  ```java
   @RequestMapping(value = "/read.html")
   public String readStudent(Model model,Long studentId) {
       Student student = null;
       studentId = 2l;
       try {
           student = serviceFile.readStudent(studentId);
       } catch(Exception e){
           model.addAttribute("message", "Some thing went wrong !!!! Exception occured");
           return "message";
       }
       model.addAttribute("student", student);
       return "read";
   }
  ```
- **Create a method that will provide that `Long` Object**
  in your controller

  ```java
   @ModelAttribute
   public void provideStudentId(Model model){
       model.addAttribute("studentId", new Long(1));
   }
  ```

---

Official Doc

```java
@RequestMapping(path = "/owners/{ownerId}/pets/{petId}/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processSubmit(@ModelAttribute Pet pet) { }
```

> Given the above example where can the Pet instance come from? There are several options:

> 1. It may already be in the model due to use of @SessionAttributes — see
>    the section called “Using @SessionAttributes to store model attributes
>    in the HTTP session between requests”.
> 2. It may already be in the model due to an @ModelAttribute method in the same controller — as explained in the previous section.
> 3. It may be retrieved based on a URI template variable and type converter (explained in more detail below).
> 4. It may be instantiated using its default constructor.

If the studentId was the parameter name sent from the UI, you can use `@RequestParam` like this

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/read.html")
public String readStudent(Model model, @RequestParam("studentId") Long studentId) {
    Student student = null;
    studentId = 2l;
    try {
        student = serviceFile.readStudent(studentId);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Some thing went wrong !!!! Exception occoured");
        return "message";
    }
    model.addAttribute("student", student);
    return "read";
}
```

Comment: @ac habahe
 i want to get this studentId dynamically from UI, when control comes into the controller ("@ModelAttribute("studentId")Long studentId") takes the id from ui and process the implementation

Comment: hi Max if the parameter name is studentId then you can use @RequestParam i am going to edit the answer to show you how

Comment: Even I have the same problem and this helped me a bit. I have a modal class in JSP. When I click the button, a form opens, which has a list of checkboxes. Initially, I got this error when I clicked the button. As you said, I removed @modalAttribute. Now, on clicking the button, the control goes directly to controller without showing the checkboxes. Also, other modal objects also go through this requestmapping only. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `studentId` field type from `Long` to `long`. It should fix it.

And one more unrelated thing that just pops to my eyes is this:

```
if (student!=null) {
  return student;
} else {
  return null;
}
```

Is exactly like saying this:

```
return student;
```

Comment: have tried with both long  / Long, getting the same error