# Getting NoSuchMethodException for java.util.List in Spring app

Tags: java, spring

How do professionals diagnose this? I can't figure out where this is coming from.

When I do a get for my home page, I get:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.List.<init>()
```

Here's the homepage Controller/template:

```
@Controller
@Slf4j
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ReciplyController {

@Autowired
RecipeService svc;


// == Model attributes ==
@ModelAttribute
public List<Recipe> recipeData(){ return svc.getAllRecipes(); }

@ModelAttribute("allUnits")
public List<Unit> unitList() {
    return Arrays.asList(Unit.ALL);
}


@RequestMapping(Mappings.HOME) // AliasFor @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getMainView(
        Model model,
        @ModelAttribute(AttributeNames.RECIPE) Recipe recipe,
        @ModelAttribute(AttributeNames.INGREDIENT_LIST) List<Ingredient> ingredientList) {

    log.info("Inside getMainView");

    if(ingredientList==null){
        log.info("ingredientList==null){");
    }


    /* Check recipeID and ingredient list exist.
     * If they don't initialize them so they can be handed to the model
     */
    if (recipe == null) {
        log.info("recipe==null");

        recipe = new Recipe();

        // Set a new recipeID
        // Log the ID
        recipe.setRecipeId(svc.generateId());
        log.info("Attached ID {} to recipe", recipe.getRecipeId());

        recipe.setIngredientList(new ArrayList<>());

        log.info("Recipe ID in process: {}", recipe.getRecipeId());
        log.info("Attached Ingredient List");

    } else  // ?recipeId set?
            // ?recipe.getIngredientList() == null
    {
        log.info("recipe!=null");

        if(recipe.getRecipeId()==null){
            recipe.setRecipeId(svc.generateId()); // Set id via service
        }

        if(recipe.getIngredientList()==null) {
            recipe.setIngredientList(new ArrayList<>());   // Initialize ingredient list
        }
    }

    //recipe has Id

    recipe.setRecipeName("Fish Pie");

    recipe.getIngredientList().add(
            new Ingredient(
                    svc.generateId(),
                    10.0,
                    Unit.CUPS.getName(),
                    "Sassifrasss"));



    model.addAttribute(AttributeNames.RECIPE, recipe);
    model.addAttribute(AttributeNames.RECIPE_ID, recipe.getRecipeId());
    model.addAttribute(AttributeNames.RECIPE_NAME, recipe.getRecipeName());
    model.addAttribute(AttributeNames.RECIPE_DATA, recipeData());

    log.info("recipe ingredient list size: {}", recipe.getIngredientList().size());
    model.addAttribute(AttributeNames.INGREDIENT_LIST, recipe.getIngredientList());

    return ViewNames.HOME;
}
```

}

Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"

          href="../static/css/home-style.css"
          th:href="@{/css/home-style.css}"/>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>


<h4>For the future, creating the template has 3 phases:
    <ol>
        <ul>Test data binding "Data draft"</ul>
        <ul>Mockup without data "Visual draft"</ul>
        <ul>Final product</ul>
    </ol>
</h4>


<!---->
<h1 id="page-title"/>
<h3 id="recipe-id"/>
<h3 id="recipe-name"/>


<!--Atm, one object is used to pass data back and
forth between view and handler -->
<form id="add-rows-form" action="#" method="post">

    <label id="add-rows-label" for="add-rows-input"></label>
    <input id="add-rows-input" type="number" name="add-rows-name"/>
    <input id="submit-add-row" type="submit" th:value="#{table.add.row}"/>
</form>


<form id="get-recalculated-recipe" action="#" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th th:text="#{table.label.quantity}">Quantity</th>
            <th>Unit</th>
            <th>Ingredient Name</th>
            <th>Multiplier</th>

        </tr>


<!--    Create div body unless ingredientlist is empty.
        This should happen once per recipe added through front-end
-->
        <div class="ingredienttable" th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(ingredientlist)}">
            <tr th:each="ingredient, iter : ${ingredientlist}">


                <td>
                    <input id="table-quantity"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="table-unit"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="table-name"/>
                </td>

<!--                <td>-->
<!--                    <input type="checkbox" name="multCheckbox"/>-->
<!--                </td>-->
<!--                <td>-->
<!--                    <input id="choose-mult"/>-->
<!--                </td>-->
                <th>
                    <button type="submit" name="addRow" th:text="#{table.mult.row}">Add row</button>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </table>
</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add the full stack and POM/Gradle dependencies

Comment: `NoSuchMethodException`=dependencies conflict so check your dependencies version

Comment: This is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807064/error-java-lang-nosuchmethodexception-java-lang-long-init-in-spring-mvc

Comment: @Shadov No in that case, his repository couldn't convert Long

Comment: Yes, but the reason (and the solution) is the same.